# Тип подчинения придаточных

Tags: синтаксис, спп

Пожалуйста, определите тип подчинения придаточных в следующем предложении: Тогда, Век­шин, мо­жешь счи­тать, что у нас сбор, раз тебе так хо­чет­ся.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь однозначно неоднородное подчинение, Вы ошибиться не могли,нет здесь другой логики: можешь считать (что?), что у нас сбор,  можешь считать(при каком условии?)раз тебе так хочется. Относятся к грамматич. основе одного предложения, но отвечают на разные вопросы, имеют разный тип.

Ларf, а ссылочку на ответы не скинете? Может, Вы не туда посмотрели, не в тот вариант? Мне тест знаком по 2014 году, 3 вариант, но там задание: Среди предложений 39–49 найдите сложноподчинённое предложение
с неоднородным (параллельным) подчинением придаточных.  И ответ- (47)Когда ему было плохо, никто из нас о товариществе не вспомнил, так что
о чём тут говорить...

А в других вариантах было и последовательное.Может, всё же невнимательно смотрели таблицу с ответами?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Нет, в таблицу я не смотрела. Работаю с сайтом Дмитрия Гущина "Сдам ГИА" (У него же "Решу ЕГЭ). Задания из ОБЗ ФИПИ, но решает, по-видимому, их команда. Ошибки случаются, но в целом сайт хороший. Мне нравится, что можно работать с учениками дистанционно. Дети решают, программа проверяет, я смотрю результат. Конечно, я все решаю и все работы пересматриваю. Поэтому ссылку могу дать только  в виде номера 462304. Вам нужно зарегистрироваться на сайте, открыть вкладку "Ученику", ввести номер. тест откроется. После прорешивания будут доступны ответы и комментарии.

Comment: Зарегистрировалась, ввела номер, пишет: "нет такой задачи"

Comment: Да, мне что-то тоже от имени ученика не открывает. Я вошла во вкладку "Учитель", там есть "Создать копию работы", Открылось, попробуйте. А я буду разбираться дальше: может, там есть ограничение на количество учащихся. Я-то только летом нашла эту возможность.

Answer (score 1):

Это параллельное (неоднородное) подчинение. Смысл такой: Если тебе хочется так считать (или если ты хочешь устроить сбор), то можешь считать, что у нас сбор.

Для сравнения:

(1) **Можешь считать, что** у нас сбор, раз тебе так хочется. Параллельное (неоднородное) подчинение.

(2) **Он сказал, что**  у нас сбор, раз мне так хочется. Здесь изъяснительная часть включает придаточное условия, это последовательное подчинение.

Comment: В Вашем предложении для сравнения - подчинение последовательное. Он сказал(что?), что я могу считать это сбором (при каком условии?), если хочется. В моем (вернее. в предложении из экзаменационного теста  в 9 классе) немного не так. Я тоже определила как неоднородное подчинение. Но авторы КИМа считают его последовательным.

Comment: Я немного изменила пример для сравнения. В заданном предложении условное придаточное не входит в изъяснительную часть, поэтому здесь не может быть последовательного подчинения.

Comment: Пожалуйста, запишите Ваше предложение с вопросами. (Я пытаюсь понять точку зрения авторов, и если в Вашем примере можно от второй части задать вопрос к третьей, то почему это нельзя сделать в исходном?)

Comment: (1) Можешь считать (что?) - что у нас сбор. Можешь считать при каком условии? - если тебе так хочется. (2) Он сказал (что?) - что у нас сбор. У нас сбор при каком условии - если мне этого хочется.

Comment: Почему к первому предложению нельзя задать такие же вопросы, как ко второму?

Comment: Наверное, нельзя сказать: он сказал (при каком условии?) - раз тебе хочется. А вообще говоря  в предложении "Он сказал, что у нас сбор, раз мне так хочется", изъяснительная часть целиком присоединяется к первому предложению, может быть, тогда вообще некорректно говорить о последовательном подчинении.

Answer (score 0):

В смысле? Первое придаточное *изъяснительное*, второе же *условное*. Это требовалось?

Comment: Нет. Не тип придаточного предложения, а тип подчинения в  предложении с несколькими придаточными